# how to use Scrapy to download image that needs cookie

Tags: python, cookies, request, scrapy, python-requests

I'm using scrapy to crawl a website
this is how I maintain the cookie jar after login

```
def start_requests(self):
    return [scrapy.Request("https://www.address.com", meta = {'cookiejar' : 1}, callback = self.post_login)]


def post_login(self, response):
    print('Preparing login')
    return [FormRequest.from_response(response,   #"http://www.zhihu.com/login",
                            meta = {'cookiejar' : response.meta['cookiejar']}, 
                            headers = self.headers,
                            formdata = {
                                'username': 'user',
                                'password': 'pass123'
                            },
                            callback = self.after_login,
                        )]
```

then, each request I will need to

```
yield scrapy.Request(curr, meta={'cookiejar':response.meta['cookiejar']}, callback=self.parse_detail)
```

Everything goes well until I need to crawl the image from the site.
I will need to use urllib.request.urlretrive(), imagePipeline of scrapy or similar tools to open the image_url.

but how can I pass my cookie jar with it? otherwise, it will be redirect to login page.

or is there a way to download the image directly with scrapy request?

Thank you, eLRuLL, for solving the problem for me
but the code need to be modified a little in python3

from io import BytesIO  instead of from StringIO import StringIO
and then use the BytesIO in the following code.

Comment: why do you need `urllib`  to make the image request? if you do a scrapy request, it will load the cookies automatically

Comment: I want to download the image, Is there a way to get image content with scrapy request?

Comment: is that your question? how to parse a scrapy response into an image object?

Comment: yes, I don't find a way to parse scrapy response to image object directly , do you know how to do that?

Comment: ok, let me answer the question then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `response.body` has the information you need, you can later parse it to what it is.

I am not entirely sure this will work for every image file type, but you can get more information in the `response.headers['content-type']` so you can know which file type it actually is and use a respective python module to handle that file type:

```
from PIL import Image
from StringIO import StringIO

...

    def parse_image(self, response):
        i = Image.open(StringIO(response.body))
        i.save("imagefile.png")
        ...
```

with that you made a scrapy request and saved the image (this is saving in the same directory as your project).

Install `PIL`  with `pip install Pillow`

Comment: appreciate your help, you save my day, let me try this method

Comment: Thanks, It works well, but in my case, I need to use BytesIO instead.

Comment: nice, great it could help!

Comment: @yixianhe please remember to accept the answer if it helped you!

Comment: @eL Rull I was trying to accept it but there is no button right now, maybe there is no votes yet?

Comment: @yixianhe you should be able to upvote now, the accept button is below the votes section

Answer (score 0):

save your cookie to item, and then custom your own pipeline to extract

```py
class MyFilesPipeline(FilesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        if 'file_urls' not in item:
            return
        adapter = ItemAdapter(item)
        for file_url in adapter['file_urls']:
            yield scrapy.Request(file_url,
                                 headers = item["headers"], 
                                 meta={
                                        'cookiejar': item['cookiejar'],
                                        })
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None, *, item=None):
            return 'files/' + os.path.basename(urlparse(request.url).path)
```